# AprilTag vs Aruco markers

Tags: computer-vision, pose

AprilTag and Aruco are both popular methods for vision-based fiducial marker pose estimation.

What are the pros and cons of each fiducial marker pose estimation systems?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Rufus, but I'm afraid that questions which ask about the Pros/cons or Advantages/disadvantages are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic.

Comment: Experimental Comparison of Fiducial Markers for Pose Estimation ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9213977

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aruco (as implemented in OpenCV)

- pros

  - Easy to set up (with readily available [aruco marker generator](http://ev.me/arucogen/), opencv & ros implementation, etc.)
  - fewer false detection (with default parameters)
- cons

  - Newer versions of aruco is GPL licensed, hence opencv is stuck on an old implementation of aruco when it was still BSD.
  - More susceptible to [rotational ambiguity](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QU9KoBtjSM2kF6ITOjQ76xqL7H0TEtXriJX5kwi9Kgc/edit#bookmark=id.ve2m6nbh7fg0) at medium to long ranges
  - More [tuning parameters](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dcd/structcv_1_1aruco_1_1DetectorParameters.html)
  - More computationally intensive

AprilTag (as implemented in [apriltag_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/apriltag_ros))

- pros

  - BSD license
  - Fewer [tuning parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/apriltag_ros/Tutorials/Detection%20in%20a%20video%20stream)
  - Works fairly well even at long range
  - Used by [NASA](https://github.com/nasa/AprilNav)
  - More flexible marker design (e.g. markers not necessarily square)
  - Less computationally intensive
  - Native support for tag bundles where multiple tags are combined to form 1 tag (using multiple tags at different orientations effectively eliminates the rotational ambiguity problem)
- cons

  - less straight forward to setup (no opencv implementation AFAIK, only ros implementation, slightly more steps to [obtain markers](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag-imgs))
  - more false detection (with default parameters)

Comment: Why "More susceptible to rotational ambiguity" for Aruco? The document you link explains that the rotational ambiguity problem exists for _any_ pose estimation of coplanar points. Given that an AprilTag is also flat, why would it suffer less from this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why, the observation was based on experimental evidence.  For marker of the same size and same distance away, rotational ambiguity occurred less frequently for AprilTag